# FB.Canvas undefined in the console

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I'm trying to resize the iFrame in my Facebook canvas app with Javascript. I know how to do this in the code- it's working fine.

However, I can't seem to get it to work in the console, for testing purposes. In the console, `FB` is defined but `FB.Canvas` is not (the closest is `FB.CanvasClient`).  Why is that? How can I test iFrame resizing in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the FB.Canvas inside the `fbAsyncInit` and after `FB.init`,
always use `window.fbAsyncInit` to run the init code after the api load.

```
//initializing API
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : APP_ID,
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });

    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width:810, height:850 });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your IFrame through developer.facebook.com

From the app you are working on click on advanced. in that page you will see canvas size. make it Fluid.